# How to mirror path in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, math

So i have a code that paints path at container.

```
 void paintWithPattern(
      Canvas canvas, double x, double y, double width, double height) {
    final maxDimension = max(width, height);
    final stripeW = maxDimension / featuresCount / 6;
    var step = stripeW * 9;
    final paint = Paint()
      ..style = PaintingStyle.fill
      ..color = bgColor;
    canvas.drawRect(Rect.fromLTWH(x, y, width, height), paint);
    final rectStripesCount =
        featuresCount * 2.5; // to make sure we cover the whole rectangle
    final allStripesPath = Path();
    for (var i = 1; i < rectStripesCount; i += 2) {
      final stripePath = Path();
      stripePath.moveTo(x - stripeW + step, y);
      stripePath.lineTo(x + step, y);
      stripePath.lineTo(x, y + step);
      stripePath.lineTo(x - stripeW, y + step);
      stripePath.close();
      allStripesPath.addPath(stripePath, Offset.zero);
      step += stripeW * 9;
    }
    paint
      ..style = PaintingStyle.fill
      ..color = fgColor;
    canvas.drawPath(allStripesPath, paint);
  }
```

The result of the code painting on container is below
[image]

How can I made it, so it's mirrored by Y axis?
like on picture below [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that with negative scaling and translation (to correct position), like this for Y axis:

```dart
canvas.scale(1, -1);
canvas.translate(0, -height);
canvas.drawPath(allStripesPath, paint);
```

For X axis:

```dart
canvas.scale(-1, 1);
canvas.translate(-width, 0);
canvas.drawPath(allStripesPath, paint);
```

Docs:

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Canvas/scale.html

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Canvas/translate.html

Comment: Thanks, that works just perfrectly